# Responsive menu: vertical on smaller but horizontal on larger screen

Tags: css, html, menu

On responsive website, I would like to display a vertical menu on smaller screens and a horizontal menu on larger screens.
 Currently, the following HTML and CSS code does NOT display a vertical menu on smaller screens. Can any one please revise/improve this code? Thanks in advance.

```css
#menu {
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 40px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: rgb(52, 85, 154); 
}
#menu a {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 4% 0px 4%;
 font: 400 16px/32px 'Courier', sans-serif;
 min-height: 40px;
 color:white;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight:bold;
 transition: .5s;  
}
#menu a:hover {
 color: red;
 background-color: blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
#menu {
 max-width: 100%;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:775px) {
#menu a {
 max-width: 100%;
 padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
 float: none;
 text-align: center;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:980px) {
#menu {
 max-width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<body>
<nav id="menu"> <a href="index.html">Home</a> <a href="aboutus.html">About</a> <a href="services.html">Services</a> <a href="http://srjtax.blogspot.com/" rel="external" target="_blank">Blog</a> <a href="taxlinks.html">Links</a> <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a> <a href="contact.html">Contact</a> 
</nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

When creating a responsive site, the main navigation is usually the trickiest because of the often requirement to display the items vertically (and within a hamburger dropdown/flyout) on a mobile screen and then horizontally on a desktop screen

The first step is to develop it using a mobile first approach. This means:

1. Style everything so that it looks good on a small screen
2. Use media queries to progressively style larger screen sizes

Here is a basic snippet of how to style a menu so that it shows vertically in a small screen and horizontally in a large screen.

```
/* Mobile style first */
.menu {
    text-align: center;
}
.menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}
.menu a:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}

/* Desktop style after */
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .menu a {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyp42ysh/) for an example

Answer (score 0):

add a `display: block;` declaration here:

```
@media screen and (max-width:775px) {
   #menu a {
       max-width: 100%;
       padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
       float: none;
       text-align: center;
       display: block;
   }
}
```

Comment: I just added the line you suggested. It works! Thanks. Now how to have show/hide feature on smaller screens so that the vertical menu occupying so much room hides?

Comment: well you can use the input checkbox method if you don't have to bother about IE8 (that case you'd need to apply a js polyfill to handle the :checked selector). I guess you want to have something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/yhcj9dsd/

Comment: Please write in details the code (jsfiddle.net/yhcj9dsd –  allienato) so I can try. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, you can scan the code on the jsfiddle I provided. this has gone beyond the scope of your main question, which I already answered

Comment: When I clicked on "jsfiddle.net/yhcj9dsd", I found the code. The MENU is toggle for hide/unhide menu elements. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code snippets

HTML
just add a span tag right above the nav tag

```
<span id='trigger'> Menu </span>
```

CSS

In the initial menu a tag definition change the display to block from inline-block and set float to left.
And then put the following:

```
#trigger {
display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 560px /* just as an example*/) {
#trigger {
    display: block;
}

#menu {
    display: none;
}

div.expand {
    display: block;
}

#menu a {
    float: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
}
```

Javascript

```
jQuery("#trigger").click(function() {

    jQuery("#menu").slideToggle(500, function() {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("expand").css('display','500');
    });

});
```

I hope this helps